# Parameter Array value is not used

Tags: python

I have these errors in my Python code:

```
Error: Shadows name Array from outer scope
```

and

```
Error: Parameter Array value is not used.
```

This is homework for my Python class and these are the requirements:

> Modify the merge sort algorithm to sort a list in descending order.

Can anyone help me out with this? This is my code:

```py
#! /usr/bin/python 
def Merge(Array, firstStart, firstEnd, secondEnd):
    n1 = firstEnd - firstStart + 1
    n2 = secondEnd = firstEnd
    Temp1 = [None] * n1
    Temp2 = [None] * n2

    for i in range(n1):   
        Temp1[i] = Array[firstStart + i]

        for i in range(n2):
            Temp2[i] = Array[firstEnd + i + 1] 
            i = 0
            j = 0

            for k in range(firstStart, secondEnd):
                if Temp1[i] >= Temp2[j]:   
                    Array[k] = Temp1[i]
                    i = i + 1 
                else: 
                    Array[k] = Temp2[j] 
                    j = j + 1 
                    return Array

def MergeSort(Array, left, right):   
   if left < right:
       mid = (left + right) / 2 
       MergeSort(Array, left, mid) 
       MergeSort(Array, mid + 1, right)
       Merge(Array, left, mid, right)
       Array = [10, 30, 40, 80, 20`, 70, 90, 60, 50]`
       MergeSort(Array, 0, 8)
       print(Array)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and fix your indentation.

Comment: The last three lines mke no sense. Is this code really correct? We can't help you with the wrong code!

Answer (score 0):

Those are not errors. They are warnings from your IDE.

Creating a local variable with the same name as something in an outer scope is perfectly acceptable. In fact, it's the whole point of scopes; I don't even know why that's a warning. I don't understand the other warning at all - it says you have an unused parameter, but I see you use it several times in that function.

You can safely ignore these warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The first warning is telling you that you have something named "Array" in your code that is hiding something at a higher level with the same name (it's probably a class) that would otherwise be available. As TigerhawkT3 says, this isn't really a problem, but you can get rid of the warning by just changing the name "Array" in your code to something else.

The second error is telling you that in the function MergeSort, you never use any values from the parameter Array. It's not quite clear where the function MergeSort ends since your indentation is messed up, but as best I can tell, you're calling Merge from MergeSort to handle actually updating the list of numbers. You could get rid of the second warning by adding a do nothing line like "_ = Array[0]" at the top or bottom of the MergeSort function.